# checking existence of secret code before registration

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I'm trying to create a private application and I'm using Symfony3 and FOSUserBundle. The administrator send an unique secret code by email to each member, and in registration the member should enter this code.
I have an entity SecretCode contains email and secret code.

What's the best way to verify existence of secret code before registration ?

```
// entity
class SecretCode
{

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="eamil", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="secret_code", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $secretCode;

//............
}
```

Comment: Use events, the `fos_user.registration.confirm` event should be suitable for that purpose. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php

Comment: @malcolm : can you explain me a bit how to do that please ?

Comment: Sorry I have no time, but in short, inside event you can fetch the `secretCode` entity and compare the secret code to the code entered by user. Never try it before, but I think the event I provided would be suitable, because it's fired just before `fos_user.registration.confirmed` event, just before user added to db.